# How to use the exit status from a function within my script

Tags: bash, function, unix, exit, status

I have a script and within it I call a function. How can I use the exit status from the function to print a message, without incorporating the message inside the function?

I am supposed to write a script which has:

Your script should contain a function `increasingNos` that uses three parameters. All three parameters should be integers. The function is a "success" (with exit status 0) if there are exactly three parameters and they are numbers in increasing order. The function should have an exit status of 1 if there are three parameters but they are not in increasing order. The function should should have an exit status of 2 if there are fewer or more than 3 parameters.

and...

you should print an appropriate message to the standard output **after** calling `increasingNos` with parameters 17 5 23 to say whether or not there were three parameters and whether or not they were numbers in increasing order. Use an `if` conditional and the exit status on your function call to do this. This `if` conditional may **not** be in the function increasingNos.

This is what I have come up; whenever I run the script, it exits when the function call hits an exit status.  How can I execute the rest of the script?

```
increasingNos(){
   if [ $# -ne 3 ];then
      exit 2
   fi
   if [ $1 -ge $2 ] || [ $2 -ge $3 ];then
      exit 1
   else
      exit 0
   fi
}
increasingNos 17 5 23
if [ $? -eq 2 ];then
   echo "You did not supply exactly 3 integer parameters!"
fi
if [ $? -eq 1 ];then
   echo "Your parameters were not input in increasing order!"
fi
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
   echo "Congrats, you supplied 3 integers in increasing order!"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `return` instead of `exit` and save the value of `$?` in a variable, because it will change after the first test.

This works:

```
increasingNos(){
   if [ $# -ne 3 ];then
      return 2
   fi
   if [ $1 -ge $2 ] || [ $2 -ge $3 ];then
      return 1
   else
      return 0
   fi
}
increasingNos 17 5 23
stat=$?
if [ $stat -eq 2 ];then
   echo "You did not supply exactly 3 integer parameters!"
fi
if [ $stat -eq 1 ];then
   echo "Your parameters were not input in increasing order!"
fi
if [ $stat -eq 0 ];then
   echo "Congrats, you supplied 3 integers in increasing order!"
fi
```

Comment: Cool; a simpler way of dealing with the problem of `$?` getting reset is to use `case "$?" in ... esac` in lieu of the indiv. `if` statements.

Comment: I was just trying to stay as close as possible to the original script from the question and that there was an additional problem.  Thanks for pointing out `case "$?" in ... esac`.

Comment: Got it. The problem of `$?` getting reset was indeed worth pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `return` rather than `exit` in your functions.